# Problem in creating image of UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimage

I want to create an UIImage of UIWebView and then I want to draw that image.

Here is my code:

```
    UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004)];
 tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempView.bounds.size);
    [tempView drawRect:tempView.bounds];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 
 CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
 CGContextDrawImage(ctx, imageRect, [image CGImage]);
```

but its not drawing anything other than a blank page. Cant we create UIImage like that or Am I doing something wrong somewhere in the code.

Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next code should work:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempView.bounds.size);
[tempView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```